# set iframe content html but don't allow access to main domain

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe in my page. I am changing the content of by using:

```
$('#myiframe').contents().find('body').html('');
```

The iframe content is from another domain. However, I noticed that anything in the content that is loaded (such as an image) via a src url starting with `/`  will load the content as if the base url is the main page's url, even though the content is from a different domain.

I have tried using the sandbox tag in the iframe but that wont allow the content to be changed at all. I have tried a base tag in the head of the iframe content but that does nothing.

Is it possible to change the content of the iframe without allowing the base url being that of the main pages url?

Comment: if i set the src of the iframe to load some content then it is okay. but i can't do it like that as i need to fetch it via ajax and then set the returned ajax request to the iframe content. that is when it seems to have the base domain set as the main windows domain. i know this because when i look at the console i am getting lots of 404s for things that are trying to load via the base domain of the main window.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem possible, but also local work you do. I'm tried